# Regular expression with optional |

Tags: php, regex

I have the next code and I'm trying to know if the string its valid based on the regular expression.
I'm trying to validate only strings that follow the next sequence.

```
lettersOrNumbersAndunderDashes=lettersOrNumbersAndUnderdashes
```

But that sequence can be repeated if there is a vertical bar.

For example `parameter1=value1|parameter2=value2|parameterN=valueN`

```
if (preg_match("/((^[A-Za-z0-9_]+=[A-Za-z0-9_]+)\|?)/m", "perPd_asd=as_3_4d|asdas=asdasd")) 
    return 'Valid';

    return 'Invalid';
```

I think I'm missing something or building a wrong regular expression.

Comment: First string only has one `=`. https://regex101.com/r/yZ4qE2/1 Also `[A-Za-z0-9_]` can be `\w`.

Comment: Can u be a little more specific on that?, i'm fairly new on regex

Comment: Your expression says `stuff` then a `=`s then `stuff`. Your first string meets that because there is the one `=`. Your second it stops after the first `=`. (my regex101 demo is inverted cause I started backwards)..

Comment: try this : https://regex101.com/r/lB6iF6/1

Comment: You can see better example here, https://regex101.com/r/yZ4qE2/2. Are you trying to separate pairings? I'd explode on `|` first then the `=`.

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone i will keep trying this fixes u guys gave me till i dig the solution. 
I got it working with the answer @Prtuhvi Raj gave me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong thing you did is putting a `^` at the beginning of the pattern, which means that it will only match if the text is at the beginning of the string. This should solve :

```
if (preg_match("/(([A-Za-z0-9_]+=[A-Za-z0-9_]+)\|?)/m", "perPd_asd=as_3_4d|asdas=asdasd")) 
return 'Valid';

return 'Invalid';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that parameter name starts from number?

You need more test cases for your regular expression, for example:

```
0=somevalue
param=value|
one_more_param=@#$%^|some_param=some-value
_=VALUE|abc=***
a=1|b=2|c=3
param=0|param=1
```

my solution is:

```
^(([_A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*=[^\|=]+)\|)*([_A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*=[^\|=]+)$
```